# jquery nth-child trouble

Tags: jquery, web, selector, css-selectors

I'm using the :nth-child selector to select certain elements

case 1:

```
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
```

and

case 2:

```
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item'>
<div class='item'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item'>
<div class='item'>
<div class='item show'>
<div class='item show'>
```

My code starts in case 1 and does $('#outerDiv .show:nth-child(3n - 2)') to select every third element. This works perfectly. Then if the user changes some settings some of the elements lose their show class and disappear of the screen and the code looks like case 2. The problem is that now when i execute the $('#outerDiv .show:nth-child(3n - 2)') selector, it still treats it as case 1 even though i can clearly see in the console that it's case 2. Am i doing something wrong. Sorry I can't post the actual code so i put up a quick example.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child` selector will **get all the elements** irrespective of the class..

Use a `$.each` and assign the class in the loop

```
​$('#outerDiv .show').each(function(i){
    if( i%3 === 0){
       $(this).addClass('a'); 
    }        
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8V5mg/)**

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to loop over them manually in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with closing the div elements.

Instead of

`<div class='item show'>`

put

```
<div class='item show'></div>
```

Here is a quick demo that selects every third (and first) element in your DOM:
http://jsfiddle.net/robertp/hVBAC/2/

I hope it is somewhat helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) functions:

```
 $('#outerDiv .show').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
 }).filter(":nth-child(3n - 2)");
```

First, filter the list of elements to those without the property `display:none`. Next, filter the nth-children.

Comment: @avovk - let me know if this doesn't solve your issue and I'll try to think of another solution.